# Post to Twitter/Facebook from Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm wondering whether there's a way to post to Twitter/Facebook (possibly using the iOS built-in accounts) from the Apple Watch?

I'd like to be able to do this within an Apple Watch application - I hope the only way to do this isn't to launch a share screen on the companion application (on the phone).

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're correct. Since there's no way to post without user interaction (otherwise things would get spammy quick), you'll have to use something like Handoff and prompt the user to open your app on their iPhone. There's no Social framework in WatchKit like in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You could get around the iOS limitation by making the user log in only once in your iOS companion app. Then build a simple backend where you'll make a request from your WatchKit extension with the parameters to post to the social network.

I think this is the only solution possible without requiring user interaction.